# Mysql Join verificar SE dado não existe em outra tabela

Tags: mysql

TABELA "perfil"

```
id  nome    
1   UserA   
2   UserB   
3   Usuario1    
4   Usuario2    
5   Usuario3    
6   Usuario4
```

TABELA "amigos"

```
id  amigo1  amigo2  status  
 2      3       2       1   
 4      4       1       1   
 5      2       5       1   
 6      1       5       1   
 7      6       1       0
```

Caso eu use o join, para retornar os amigos, funciona OK (uso como base o id=1 / UserA)

```
SELECT perfil.id, perfil.nome,amigos.amigo1, amigos.amigo2, amigos.status FROM perfil
INNER JOIN amigos ON ((amigos.amigo1 = perfil.id) OR (amigos.amigo2 = perfil.id))
WHERE perfil.id != 1 AND (amigos.amigo1 = 1 or amigos.amigo2 = 1) AND amigos.status = '1' GROUP BY perfil.id ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12
```

Me retorna

```
id  nome     amigo1 amigo2  status  
 4  Usuario     4        1       1  
 5  Usuario3    1        5       1
```

Minha duvida é, não consigo retornar os valores de quem não é amigo do ID 1 / UserA

O Join dessa maneira (aplicando no WHERE !=1 (ID 1):

```
SELECT perfil.id, perfil.nome, amigos.amigo1, amigos.amigo2, amigos.status FROM perfil
INNER JOIN amigos ON ((amigos.amigo1 = perfil.id) OR (amigos.amigo2 = perfil.id)) 
WHERE perfil.id != 1 AND (amigos.amigo1 != 1 or amigos.amigo2 != 1) GROUP BY perfil.id ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12
```

Resulta:

```
id  nome    amigo1  amigo2  status  
6   Usuario4    6       1       0   
5   Usuario3    2       5       1   
4   Usuario2    4       1       1   
2   UserB       3       2       1   
3   Usuario1    3       2       1
```

**Meu objetivo é que o join faça não aparecer o Usuario3 (ID 5) na lista, pois ele consta como amigo do ID 1.**

Comment: SELECT perfil.id, perfil.nome, amigos.amigo1, amigos.amigo2, amigos.status FROM perfil
LEFT JOIN amigos ON ((amigos.amigo1 = perfil.id) OR (amigos.amigo2 = perfil.id)) 
WHERE perfil.id != 1 AND (amigos.amigo1 IS NULL ) GROUP BY perfil.id ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12


Tenta desta forma

Comment: Retornou em branco, nenhum dado recuperado

Comment: Guilherme, acho que eu havia entendido sua dúvida errada.

Tente assim: 

SELECT perfil.id, perfil.nome,amigos.amigo1, amigos.amigo2, amigos.status FROM perfil
INNER JOIN amigos ON ((amigos.amigo1 = perfil.id) OR (amigos.amigo2 = perfil.id))
WHERE perfil.id != 1 AND (amigos.amigo1 != 1 and amigos.amigo2 != 1) AND amigos.status = '1'

Comment: @LucasBrogni então meu querido amigo, infelizmente o resultado ainda não foi esperado (mesmo eu fazendo alguns ajustes removendo o status,etc), ainda aparece outros usuários (ID 5 / Usuario3 e duplicidade do userB) na busca, a remoção do agrupamento tornou menos eficaz, e informação complementar: o status tem que ser diferente de 1(status:1 significa amigo), de preferencia NULL.

Comment: Se serve de apoio para a vossa colaboração, esse script (pastebin) é o que já uso atualmente, ele "serve" mas é extremamente ineficaz https://pastebin.com/Jy0XsSaC
(desconsidere os campos desnecessários a questão)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
selecionar todos que nao sao amigos do id=1
**/
SELECT *
FROM perfil p
WHERE
 id!=1
AND
 id NOT IN (
 SELECT pa.id
 FROM perfil p
 JOIN amigos a ON (a.amigo1=p.id OR a.amigo2=p.id)
 JOIN perfil pa ON pa.id=IF(a.amigo1=p.id, a.amigo2, a.amigo1) 
 WHERE p.id=1
 AND a.status=1
);
```